# proposition and conclusions : logically solve a problem

Tags: logic

```
 If the proposition 'domestic animals are hardly ferocious' is taken to be 
 false, which of the following proposition/propositions
 can be claimed to be certainly true ? 

 Select the correct code:
```

`Propositions :
(a) All domestic animals are ferocious
(b) Most of the domestic animals are ferocious
(c) No domestic animal is ferocious
(d) some domestic animals are non-ferocious`

code:-

```
 (1) (b) only 
 (2) (a) and (b) 
 (3) (a) only 
 (4) (c) and (d)
```

How to logically approach the problem ?

### My workout:

'domestic animals are hardly ferocious' if taken into false it becomes 'most of the domestic animals are ferocious' so the answer is option (a)

is this the correct way to approach?

The correct answer given by the university is option 2 which is a and b.  I donot know how the university derived this answer

source : 
http://netexam.pmgurus.com/ugc-net-online-questions.aspx?q=solved-ugcnet-paper--july2018&gid=92&h=1&QID=6105&Qno=17

Comment: what about all domestic animals are ferocious?

Comment: Hardly is taken as some not I.e particular negative. According to the square of opposition the true can be all domestic animals are ferocious via contradiction and some domestic animals are ferocious via sub alternation. Hope this helps you.

Comment: It may be helpful to provide some explanation or some reference to help the OP learn what the technical terms "contradiction" and "sub alternation" stand for.